# update strategy for npm packages of expo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, expo

I wonder what the update strategy for expo is when using expo-cli.
F.e. my package currently consists of these packages:

```
"expo": "39.0.4",
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-dom": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.4.tar.gz",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "1.7.0",
"react-native-reanimated": "1.13.1",
"react-native-web": "0.14.8",
```

Normally when i do default react applications i just add renovate-bot to my repo and update everything all the time. Things seem to be different when using expo. Some questions:

When i updated `react-native-gesture-handler` or `react-native-reanimated` i got warnings when running `expo start` that these versions are out of range for my currently running expo package. Is it correct that i should not update those dependend packages until `expo` releases an update?

When i updated `react` to 17 no such warning popped up, so it seems expo is fine when i run newer version of `react`? (although i had other runtime warnings pop up related to it)

Why is `react-native` fixed to this specific version? I guess because `expo` expects an exact version? Is this when `expo upgrade` should be used once a new expo version gets released?

Thanks for answering any of these questions.